# How to parse all content of a div into 1 element in a list instead of multiple using xpath and lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

I have multiple divs with a class of text on a website that look like this:

```
<div class="text">
"test1"
<br>
"test2"
<br>
"test3"
<br>
</div>
```

When I use the following code to obtain the text in these divs, I end up with 3 separate elements in my list, when I really just want 1 element in my list for each div.

```
mytext = tree.xpath('//*[@class="text"]/text()')
print(mytext)
```

I get:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

But I really want:

```
['test1\ntest2\test3']
```

I can settle for with or without the newline characters because I can strip them out. I imagine there has to be a way to do this with xpath. Otherwise I'm thinking I will have to use iterparse()?

Comment: please can you just post the whole code once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps  you to get text in the div than follows `<br/>`'s can be retrieved by:

```
    //*[@class="text"]/text()[preceding-sibling::br]
```

Technically, between `br` tags would mean:

```
 //*[@class="text"]/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just join the result in Python

```
mytext = tree.xpath('//*[@class="text"]/text()')
print('\n'.join(mytext))
```

Alternatively you can apply functions in your xpath expression, e.g. normalize-space, would give you one string but then you still have get the newline characters into  the string...

```
tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="text"])')
-> '"test1""test2""test3"'
```